# TGLspacetext in a moving plane + panning (source code

Tags: 3d

The DelphiXE7 + GLscene source code which can be downloaded in http://www.cognitor.com.br/IsolinesSF.zip  permit to create isolines in a PlaneXY from a set of 3D points. The plane can be moved and the isolines are created in each position of the plane. Just compile and run to see. 
The GLcontouring.SFC.pas used in the code has differences from the GLcontouring.pas (GLscene site) just to permit writing the values of some of the isolines.
The code works but there are points that I could not solve ( a to c below) for which I need your help :
a)  When we run the code, the isolines are showed correctly and the values are correctly written. I would like that the letters more easily visible but not increasing the font size. The font size is selected as a function of the size of the plane .
b)  If I move the plane the fonts (TGlspacetext ) the isolines are redrawn correctly but the letters of the previous position of the plane remains there . Only the ones in the plane should be visible
c)  When I close the program sometimes I get an error “Access violation”
d)  Another welcome improvement would be to see the fonts from both sides of the plane – in the right position for reading
e)  How could I do the panning of the screen in the horizontal or vertical position?
Historic in my previous post about Isolines
Thank you, in advance,  for your help !
If anyone wants to write me directly, my email is sergiofeitoza@cognitor.com.br

Comment: Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for this site. Either if someone takes the effort to answer your questions, it cannot be used by others facing similar issues. Please try to narrow down the source code involved and add them to your question. Do not give your mail address, because private conversation also does not help the community.

Comment: Please also take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). A wall of text usually does not attract many readers.